# Assignment for my study

Tags: java, arrays

Write an Java apps that accepts 100 integer numbers from a user. The input should be in  the range of 1-200.the program will display the number of integers in the following categories:

```
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
…
…
191-200
```

> Your program should have a void method that will do these tasks. It has one parameter that represents the input values in the form of `int[]` as shown below:
>
> `void displayStatistics( int[] input)`

Please help me everyone.I'm no idea what to do next.

The code is like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter number and 0 for stop.");
    int enter = reader.nextInt();
    while ( enter != 0)
    {
        if ((enter >= 1) && (enter <= 200))
        {
            array.add(enter);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Number range is 1-200");
        }

         enter= reader.nextInt();    
    }

    void displayStatistics(int[] input)
    {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        int Nombor1 = ((i-1) * 10) + 1;
        int Nombor2 = (i * 10);
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print((Number1 + "-" + Number2 +"   ===>"));
        for (int number : array)

        {
            if ((number >= Number1) && (number <= Number2))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)

            System.out.print(x+1);

            System.out.println();
    }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: So, just out of interest, what were you doing during the classes where they taught you this stuff? Or is your educational institution sadistic in testing you on stuff they never taught?

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure your program compiles and test it to see what it does.  If you use an IDE, it will show you if the code is compiling as you type and can help you format the code.

When it doesn't do what you expect you can use your debugger to step through the code to work out why it does what it does.

---

For your interest, and you have a method which appears to work, here is how I would write displayStatistics

```
static void displayStatistics(int[] ints) {
    int[] count = new int[20];
    for (int i : ints) count[(i - 1) / 10]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
        System.out.printf("%d to %d : %d%n", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10, count[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, some remarks on the code you show.

- You cannot put a method inside another. Move displayStatistics() out of main().
- Care to indent correctly your code from the start. It helps in getting correct code.
- Follow Java conventions: write `nombor1`, not `Nombor1`.
- After the scan of the range, `println` the `count`, there is no point in looping over this value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i can make the code works.:)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the main method.

Then you need to call the displaystatistics method.
You can change that method to a static one, or create a new instance of your class.

Either way, you don't need to pass it the variable "input[]" since you declared "array" to be static.

Then, just show the result.

I corrected your program a little bit, so this should work, but it won't be the most efficient way to go about this.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Masukkan nombor antara 1-200 dan 0 untuk berhenti.");
    int masuk = reader.nextInt();
    while ( masuk != 0 ) {
        if ( (masuk >= 1) && (masuk <= 200) ) {
            array.add(masuk);

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Nombor mesti antara 1-200");
        }
        masuk = reader.nextInt();
    }
    displayStatistics();
}

static void displayStatistics() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        int Nombor1 = ((i - 1) * 10) + 1;
        int Nombor2 = (i * 10);
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print((Nombor1 + "-" + Nombor2 + "   ===>"));
        for (int nombor : array) {
            if ( (nombor >= Nombor1) && (nombor <= Nombor2) ) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        /*for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            System.out.print(x + 1);
        }*/
        System.out.print(count);
        count = 0;

        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: "Either way, you don't need to pass it the variable "input[]" since you declared "array" to be static."  What do you mean by that? How about if i not declared it to be static? Can i pass it into "input[]" variable?

Comment: A static array is visible to the class.  
A non static array is a member of an object (instance) of the class.  
So the static array will be accessible without passing it, while the non static counterpart needs to be passed.  

Another way to do it would be to remove the static modifier from the array and the displaystatistics class, and call the displayStatistics from an instance of the class ('StatisticsClass sc = new StatisticsClass(); sc.displayStatistics;)

Comment: (ignore above confusing explanation) Visit [this link](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html) to find out the difference between static and nonstatic, and their visibility.